# Autoform reference specific field within array

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm trying to use an autoform to update an array object within a collection. The collection contains lots of information however with this form I only want to update the careerHistory. I would like to be able to control the layout of the form using bootstrap columns. To do this I need to be able to reference `careerHistory.$.company` and `careerHistory.$.title` independently. Currently, I'm only able to render the form by referencing `name="careerHistory"`. Whenever I try to reference the specific field within the array the form doesn't print.

Path: `Profile.js`

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import { addressSchema } from '../../sharedSchemas/addressSchema.js';

SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

export const Profile = new Mongo.Collection('Profile');

Profile.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
  }
});    

Schemas.Profile = new SimpleSchema({
      userId: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
      },
      'careerHistory.$': Object,
      'careerHistory.$.company': {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
      },
      'careerHistory.$.title': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
    });

Profile.attachSchema(Schemas.Profile);
```

Path: `Profile.html`

```
{{#autoForm collection=profileCollection doc=profile id="candidateCareerHistory" type="update"}}
  {{> afArrayField name="careerHistory"}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Path: `Profile.js`

```
profile() {
  return Profile.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
},
profileCollection() {
  return Profile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this if you use the [`afEachArrayItem`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#afeacharrayitem) block helper and build your chart for the specific fields you are after.  Here is an example.

```
{{#autoForm collection=Profile doc=profile id="candidateCareerHistory" type="update-pushArray" scope="careerHistory"}}
  {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name="careerHistory"}}
    <div class="panel-body has-error">
      <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name="careerHistory"}}}</span>
    </div>
  {{/if}}

  {{#afEachArrayItem name="careerHistory"}}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary autoform-remove-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
    {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.company}}  
    {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.title}}
  {{/afEachArrayItem}}
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary autoform-add-item" data-autoform-field="careerHistory"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Now you can style your fields using whatever mechanism you want.  Note, you will have to add in your own "add" and "remove" buttons when you build a form this way.  I have included the default add/remove above.

Please refer to the [default template](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/devel/templates/bootstrap3/components/afArrayField/afArrayField.html) for a full bootstrap styling example.

Comment: Thanks @jordanwillis. The only solution I found was to create a custom template, however, that seems really messy. Your solution is much cleaner. The only thing it's missing is error messages. How do you get error messages to display? I've tried `{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name="careerHistory"}}
<div class="panel-body has-error">
  <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name="careerHistory"}}}</span>
</div>
{{/if}}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: That should work.  did you add it in the correct place (outside of the `afEachArrayItem` block)?  See my updated answer.

Comment: I think I might be doing something fundamentally wrong. I'm using the new npm simple-schema and autoform 6.0 and I get no validation on any form I create at all. Am I suppose to add something to the schema?

Comment: Do you also have collection2-core installed and did you [attach your schema to the collection](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core/blob/master/README.md#attaching-a-schema-to-a-collection)?

Comment: I've updated the schema above. I'm using collection2-core, not sure how I get it to return the error. What am I missing, in my old meteor app this worked.

Comment: Hmmm...I donno. Let me try a test when I get up in the morning.

Comment: That would be very helpful

Comment: is it because I'm missing a method??

Comment: Sorry man I still haven't had a chance to test this yet. It took about 60 minutes to upgrade meteor and install all the packages and I had to walk away from it till tomorrow.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are not using an actual `Mongo.Collection` instance for your autoform collection attribute.  Your collection instance is `Profile` but you are passing in some var called `profileCollection`.  Is this a template helper and if so are you sure you are returning the collection instance (e.g. `Profile`)?  If so, then I'm wondering if you need to set the autoform type to [`update-pushArray`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#update-pusharray) instead since this form is adding to an array in your collection.

Comment: @bp123 see my updated answer based upon my previous comment.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the helpers I'm using. My form populates with profile data so I assumed I was referencing the collection correctly. I've tried to remove the helpers and use `collection=Profile doc=this` as per the autoform documentation suggests but the form disappears and I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDefinition' of undefined` within the console. The problem isn't related to pushArray. I'm not getting errors returning for any of the forms when I use the `helpers` above.